# Set up non-index.html home page to change daily

Tags: web-hosting

I have a shell account on a remote server that provides basic Web hosting. (It's a NetBSD host mainly for developer/sysadmin gurus.) I am only a user with no super-user privileges. I want to upload a new static Webpage every day to be the homepage and I don't want it to be `index.html`, rather, something like `20170108.html`, a file name that will change everyday with each new static page upload. I realize I could just upload and rename `<today's date>.html` to `index.html`, but is there a less kludged way?

Comment: how would you upload your files? do you have access to ssh?

Comment: Yes, this is a shell account with ssh. I'd probably automate the upload with cron or something. I'm using Emacs org-mode. There's a bunch of nifty "use org-mode to blog" how-tos, but I'm pressed for time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have access to *ssh*, just copy your file replacing the server's index.html file `scp <localfile.html> <remoteuser>@<remoteserver>:<remote-path>/index.html` for example:

```
scp 20170108.html webuser@myserver.com:/var/www/index.html
```

You can place that in a shell script take a file as the first parameter, for example `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp $1 webuser@myserver.com:/var/www/index.html
```

Then you can make a script to take  file with the current day as the first parameter to the server

```
$ ./script.sh `date +%Y%m%d`.html
```

would execute

```
$ scp 20170108.html webuser@myserver.com:/var/www/index.html
```

Putting that in a cronjob should be trivial.

- You can use Tramp mode to copy the files from Emacs itself.